# Uncaught Error: no such method 'value' for selectmenu widget instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I've installed the 1.10 version of jQuery and I am getting this error when trying to set the value as the way I've always done so with the selectmenu widget.

> Error: Uncaught Error: no such method 'value' for selectmenu widget instance

```
$('select.widthOpts').selectmenu('value', wDims.feet);
```

I also receive the same error when attempting to set the index of the selectmenu.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the selectmenu plugin as well?

Comment: That did it. thank you very much! I do not know why I try to attach jQuery to owing that selectmenu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you aware there are two versions?

https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/ (old, fork of filament groups work)
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/selectmenu (new, official)

The new one does not have value or index methods.

Since you are getting error, I reckon you are using new version.

So you should use `$('select.widthOpts').selectedIndex=index;`
where index is a integer value that you already know the position of the required option in selectmenu

Comment: Where do i find out how to handle the index and value from what the selectmenu use to be? Because I need to be about to set the index and value like before. What is the work around, and can you tell me how to find the docs located at github? I am new to github

Comment: Which version you are using? Old version has methods for this. In the new version you will need to get these values from the original select:

`mySelect[0].selectedIndex` and `mySelect[0].value`

ps: would you mind +1 my answer?

Comment: .selectedIndex will return the index and to set the index use .prop('selectedIndex', index_value);

Answer (score 11):

the below code also works fine. I am using jQuery 1.10.2 and jquery-ui 1.11.1

```
$('select.widthOpts').val(wDims.feet).selectmenu('refresh')
```

Comment: That's the only sollution that worked for me too,  jQuery 2.1.3 and jquery-ui 1.11.4