# jquery-ui selectmenu - Encountered "no such method 'instance' for menu widget instance" while loading dropdown options dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I have a drop down list(select list) with ID `TestList`.

I want to use this as `selectmenu` from jQuery UI. This drop down is getting dynamically populated so initially there are no options to this select list. 
In the scripts section, I am first initializing the select list with select menu as:

```
$("#TestList").selectmenu();
```

Next, I want to dynamically populate it with data, so I am doing this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {           
   $('#TestList').val(data[i]);
    $("#TestList").selectmenu("refresh");
}
```

But the problem is, it throws **Uncaught Error: no such method 'instance' for menu widget instance.**

I followed [How to select an option in a jQuery ui selectmenu dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444788/how-to-select-an-option-in-a-jquery-ui-selectmenu-dynamically) but the problem still persists.
I am using the latest jQuery UI package(jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom) and jQuery 1.9
Please help me solve this issue..
List:

[image]

Comment: In your source code can you please provide the array for `data`? And do you want select the option with value `refresh`?

Comment: Are you asking the potential values of `data`? If so, then the array would contain values of color like 'red', 'blue', 'green' etc. Also, yes I want to store selected value in DB hence I am using `refresh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/0mkkzkf5/).

This DEMO:

> 1. Dynamically initializes the `selectmenu` widget on the HTML dropdown
> 2. Dynamically create/load options
> 3. Dynamically select a specific option in the dropdown

I think it would of great help to you!

Here is the complete code from the DEMO:

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $('#initialize').click(function() {
        $( "#speed" ).selectmenu();
      $('#status').html('The widget is now initialized. But it is still empty and does not contain any options.');
      $('#add_options').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('#initialize').attr('disabled','');
    });


        $('#add_options').click(function() {
        // Add a new option to the dropdown
        $('#speed').append($('<option>', {
          value: 1,
          text: 'Option 1'
      }));
      $('#speed').append($('<option>', {
          value: 2,
          text: 'Option 2'
      }));
      $('#speed').append($('<option>', {
          value: 3,
          text: 'Option 3'
      }));
      //Refresh the selectmenu widget so the newly added options to the dropdown are now loaded properly
      $( '#speed' ).selectmenu( "refresh" );

      $('#status').html('The new options are now added dynamically!!');
      $('#select_option').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('#add_options').attr('disabled','');
    });

    $('#select_option').click(function() {
        $( '#speed' ).val(3);
      $( '#speed' ).selectmenu( "refresh" );

      $('#status').html('Options 3 is now selected!!');
      $('#select_option').attr('disabled','');
    }); 
  });
  </script>

 <div class="demo">
 <input type="button" value="Initialize the Widget" id="initialize"/>
 <br><br>
 <input type="button" value="Dynamically Add New Options" id="add_options" disabled/>
 <br><br>
 <input type="button" value="Select the 'Option 3'" id="select_option" disabled/>
<form action="#">
  <br>
  <div id="status" style="font-weight:bold;">This is the simple default HTML dropdown</div>
  <br>
    <label for="speed">Select a speed</label>
    <select name="speed" id="speed">
    </select>

</form>

</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant work done there mate! But I am still getting `Uncaught Error: no such method 'instance' for menu widget instance.` on page load i.e even before populating the list the error is shown on the console. I am using jQuery 1.9. Is this the reason?

Comment: I guess it was because I had written inside document.ready function so it seems to have been solved :)

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: The select list looks weird. It's height and width are not proper.. This is originally a bootstrap select list. Is this the reason for such deformity?

Comment: If you would use multiple jquery plugins to manipulate the HTML elements then they would surely cause layout issues because the css rules would conflict